# What is the pathogenuc mechanism of brown pigment lipofuscin in muscle atrophy?

Tags: muscles, pathogenesis, autophagy

I think it is autophagy. Lysosomal degradation. Autophagocytosis.

Example of the brown pigment (lipofuscin) here:

[image]

I am not sure if autophagy is the right answer to the "pathogenic" mechanism of atrophy.

**Is autophagy the pathogenic mechanism of atrophy?**
Or **what pathogenic mechanism is involved if you see lipofuscin in the histologic slide?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple answer: Atrophy through autophagy.

Comment: Downvoter! Please, comment or answer better.